# How to compute starttimes and endtimes of temporally consecutive grouped events from durations

Tags: r, dplyr

I have `dur`ation values of temporally consecutive grouped events:

```
df <- data.frame(
  grp = c("A", "B", "A", "C", "C", "A", "B", "A"),
  dur = c(111,222,33,10,555,333,600,222)
)
```

What I need to do is compute the starttimes and endtimes of the grouped events. All I *can* do is compute the endtimes but I'm unable to compute the starttimes (they start by `0` for each `grp`):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  mutate(
    Endtime = cumsum(dur)
  )
# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   grp [3]
  grp     dur Endtime
  <chr> <dbl>   <dbl>
1 A       111     111
2 B       222     222
3 A        33     144
4 C        10      10
5 C       555     565
6 A       333     477
7 B       600     822
8 A       222     699
```

How can the starttimes be computed?

**EDIT**:

I guess this is the solution:

```
df %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  mutate(
    Endtime = cumsum(dur),
    Starttime = Endtime -dur
  )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
df <- data.frame(
  grp = c("A", "B", "A", "C", "C", "A", "B", "A"),
  dur = c(111,222,33,10,555,333,600,222)
)

library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = F)
df %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  mutate(starttime = lag(cumsum(dur), default = 0) + 1,
    Endtime = cumsum(dur)
  )
#> # A tibble: 8 x 4
#> # Groups:   grp [3]
#>   grp     dur starttime Endtime
#>   <chr> <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 A       111         1     111
#> 2 B       222         1     222
#> 3 A        33       112     144
#> 4 C        10         1      10
#> 5 C       555        11     565
#> 6 A       333       145     477
#> 7 B       600       223     822
#> 8 A       222       478     699
```

---

Or you want to start these at 0

```r
df %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  mutate(starttime = lag(cumsum(dur), default = 0),
    Endtime = cumsum(dur)
  )
#> # A tibble: 8 x 4
#> # Groups:   grp [3]
#>   grp     dur starttime Endtime
#>   <chr> <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 A       111         0     111
#> 2 B       222         0     222
#> 3 A        33       111     144
#> 4 C        10         0      10
#> 5 C       555        10     565
#> 6 A       333       144     477
#> 7 B       600       222     822
#> 8 A       222       477     699
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, c("starttime", "Endtime") :=  
    .(shift(cumsum(dur), fill = 0) + 1, cumsum(dur)), grp]
```

-ouptut

```
df
   grp dur starttime Endtime
1:   A 111         1     111
2:   B 222         1     222
3:   A  33       112     144
4:   C  10         1      10
5:   C 555        11     565
6:   A 333       145     477
7:   B 600       223     822
8:   A 222       478     699
```